# Getting MEP error while deploying .aar file on Axis2 Server

Tags: apache-axis, aar

I am tying to deploy .aar file but everytime i encountered an error.
Logs below:

org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: An unsupported message exchange pattern (MEP) exists in ID is http://www.w3.org/2006/01/wsdl/in-out.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when I was using axis2-1.7.3-bin distribution but just replacing this latest distribution with some older axis distribution helped me to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, worked for me after switching to axis 1.6.4